# How can I use useNavigation(),...(hooks) on objected Routes?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I know I can't use hooks like that, but show you what I meant to do, routes of this proj are in Objects, and when I want to write action for headerRight to open Drawer navigation, I have no solution for that.

```
const tabRouter ={
  Calendar: {
    name: 'Calendar',
    component: Calendar,
    options: {
      tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => {
        let iconName;
        iconName = focused ? 'calendar-alt' : 'calendar-alt';

        // You can return any component that you like here!
        return <Icon name={iconName} size={size} color={color} />;
      },
      headerRight: () => (
          <Button onPress={() => {
          let navigation = useNavigation()                             <===
          navigation.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())              <===
          }}>
          <Text>jojojojo</Text>
        </Button>
      ),
      tabBarActiveTintColor: '#fff',
      tabBarInactiveTintColor: 'grey',
      tabBarItemStyle: {
        backgroundColor: theme.brand_primary,
      }
    }
  },
export default TabRouter;
```

}

error:
index.bundle?platfor…&runModule=t…:21971 Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
   See https://reactjs.org/link/invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Comment: Why not using this hook in the underlying screen ?

Comment: what version of react-navigation are you using? Im not familiar with that way of creating a Tab Navigator

Comment: Because you are using useNavigation in function. it's hook of @react-navigation. by rule of Hook, you can't use it inside a function. please provide more source code for drawer navigator.